# creating a static HTML/JS/PHP page

Tags: javascript, html

i need to create a static page that allows me to code HTML/JS/PHP that connects to a separate MYSQL backend.

how can i achieve such in wordpress page?

Answer (score 1):

> i need to create a static page that allows me to code HTML/JS/PHP...

Create a custom [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and integrate your structure in it.

> .. that connects to a separate MYSQL backend.

I don't know why you want a separate MySQL backend. In your [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109008/creating-a-static-html-js-php-page#comment151952_109009), you tell that you're making a contact form. I guess you'll want to save messages in your database. You could just create a table manually in PHPMyAdmin (or [make a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) that does it for you).

You can then use the [WPDB Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to easily connect to your current database and manipulate data in your added table.

As a side note, I strongly recommend you to [prepare your queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) before any operation.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a MYSQL database outside use `global $wpdb`. What do you need it for (I need more info to be able to help you)? Look in to either writing a custom post type or create a custom template.

see codex for more info http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: im creating a custom HTML form and the values will be stored in the database. and was thinking to create a separate DB for all those fields aside from the existing DB where my WP resides.

not sure how i can utilize the WP database so all my form fields will be stored there instead. but im limited to my knowledge thats why i opted to create another DB where my FORM submitted values will be stored.

let me know if you have other good ideas how i can address my issue.

Comment: I would advice you on looking at already existing plugins, since what you are asking for is quite complex and can´t really be answered here or you have to write one your self. There is a third way: Look in to custom templates and write your form straight in to it (this is not recommended)

Comment: what i really am creating is a contact form with conditional statements. (like, if i click this button, this textbox appears) sort of instructions. the ones available requires me to purchase to have that kind of features and the reason why i decided to code my own. I just need a static page where i can code HTML/JS/PHP to create my own conditional contact form.

Comment: Look at contact form 7 it is a contact form that have functions that you might need.